# Goosebumps book about 2 kids in a haunted school

Tags: identification-request, short-stories, goosebumps

I remember reading a book, quite a long time ago, about a guy who is sent to a haunted school, where all the children are ghosts, except for a single girl, who is human like him, and she help in formulating an escape plan, but while they escape the guy notices a grave with the girl's name and it is revealed she was a ghost too who just helped him escape because she sorta liked him

It was probably a goosebumps book, but i cant, for the love of god, remember the name of the book. If anyone recognises it from its plot given above, please inform me

Comment: Hi & Welccome : As was the habit of Sherlock Holmes I should like to add 'omit no detail however slight'  as it may have a bearing on identifying your book :) .It may be helpful to peruse this page :https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info .Dates when read , when published , cover art are vlauable too .

Comment: If someone does post a correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be mixing up two *Goosebumps* books. Searching about a *Goosebumps* book about a haunted school will quickly bring up #59, *[The Haunted School](https://goosebumps.fandom.com/wiki/The_Haunted_School)*, which involves a school with ghosts in it (albeit just one class), with one helping the protagonists escape.

> When 12-year-old Tommy Frazer moves to a new town and begins attending a new school, he decides to help decorate for the upcoming school dance in order to meet people. Thalia Halpert-Rodis, a beautiful, kind, blonde-haired girl who always wears a lot of makeup and red lipstick who is also working on the dance, requests red paint and Tommy offers to get it for her. Along the way he hears a voice, but nobody is there. He meets a tall girl with eerie, gray eyes named Greta while on his way back to the gym. He also gets lost and stumbles across a room marked "The Class of 1947". Inside are statues of twenty-five children; the principal appears and explains that these statues are in memory of the twenty-five children of 1947 who mysteriously disappeared after getting their class picture taken.
>
> On the night of the dance, Tommy and his friend Ben Jackson need to fix a banner. While searching for needed materials, they find an elevator. They start pressing buttons, but the elevator doesn't move. They look of a ‘Door Open’ button, but they can't find one. They see a button that they think might open the doors. Once they press it, nothing happens. Then they see a red button, which they push. But, instead of an alarm going off they see that the elevator is now going sideways. This transports them to a classroom in Grayworld, a place where everything is in black and white. Here they meet Seth Cortez and his friends, Eddie, Mona, Eloise, and Mary who became a few of the members of the Missing Class of 1947 and who have not aged even after all that time. Seth tells them the story of how a photographer named Mr. Chameleon sent them to this colorless world with his camera during the class photo. Everyone was transported to this world and gradually lost their color.

....

> Though she was back in the real world, Thalia also discovered she was still without color, so she hid this condition by constantly putting on makeup. Not knowing what else to do, she had stayed around the school looking for a way back into Greyworld to save her friends. Now, after being in the real world for a while, she decides that both she and her friends are better off in Greyworld. Using her lipstick, she opens a doorway for Tommy and Ben to escape while she and her friends stay behind.

The book with the revelation via gravestone that the person helping (well, ostensibly helping) was one of the ghosts may be #1 *[Welcome to Dead House](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welcome_to_Dead_House)*, which does not involve a school directly.

> He tells them that he has already found their parents and that he will take the kids to join their parents. Although Amanda and Josh think he's saving them at first, a gravestone reveals Mr. Dawes is also dead. He explains to the children that Dark Falls used to be a normal town years ago, but a yellow gas escaped from a nearby factory and spread throughout the town, transforming the citizens into the undead. Amanda and Josh manage to escape Mr. Dawes after Josh hits him on the head with his flashlight. It turns out the dead children are mutated ghouls that crumble under light, and they knock down a tree to kill all of the living dead. They rescue their parents and go home to quickly pack up.